# Unable to parse some information from a webpage using search keywords

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script to parse some information related to some songs from a website. When I try with [this link](https://www.billboard.com/music/Adele) or [this one](https://www.billboard.com/music/3T), I get my scrpt working flawlessly. What I could understand is that when I append my search keyword after this portion `https://www.billboard.com/music/`, I get the desired page having information.

However, things go wrong when I try with these keywords `1 Of The Girls` or `Al B. Sure!` or `Ashford & Simpson` and so on.

I can't figure out how to append the above keywords after the base link `https://www.billboard.com/music/` to locate the pages with information.

Script I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LINK = "https://www.billboard.com/music/Adele"

res = requests.get(LINK)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
scores = [item.text for item in soup.select("[class$='-history__stats'] > p > span")]
print(scores)
```

Result I'm getting (as expected):

```
['4 No. 1 Hits', '6 Top 10 Hits', '13 Songs']
```

Result located in that page is just after the `chart history` like the following:

[image]

How can I fetch some information from a webpage using critical search keywords?

Comment: The URL will likely need to use some encoding, like `I%27ll+be+damned` or `Ashford+%26+Simpson`. Experiment on the live site, and search for `urlencode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know all use cases but the obvious pattern I have seen for cases mentioned is that special characters are stripped (without leaving whitespace in their place) out, words are lower-case and then spaces replaced with "-". The tricky bit may be the definition and handling of special characters.

e.g.

`https://www.billboard.com/music/ashford-simpson`

`https://www.billboard.com/music/al-b-sure`

`https://www.billboard.com/music/1-of-the-girls`

You could start with writing something to perform those string manipulations and then test the response code. Perhaps see if there is any form of validation in js files.

EDIT:

Multiple blanks between words becomes single blank before being replaced with "-" ?

Answer developed with @Mithu for preparing search terms:

```
import re
keywords = ["Y?N-Vee","Ashford & Simpson","Al B. Sure!","1 Of The Girls"]
spec_char = ["!","#","$","%","&","'","(",")","*","+",",",".","/",":",";","<","=",">","?","@","[","]","^","_","`","{","|","}","~",'"',"\\"]

for elem in keywords:
    refined_keywords = re.sub('-+','-' , ''.join(i.replace(" ","-") for i in elem.lower() if i not in spec_char))
    print(refined_keywords)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @QHarr. Things become more confusing when this search keyword `U.N.L.V` resulted in this link `https://www.billboard.com/music/unlv`

Comment: That still seems to follow in that the special characters are removed and as there is no white space it is then treated as a single word and lower cased.

Comment: If I go on with my existing logic then `Ashford & Simpson` becomes `Ashford--Simpson` whereas how I like it to be is `Ashford-Simpson`.

Comment: Multiple blanks between words becomes single blank before being replaced with "-" ?

Comment: So, you leave me no choice without accepting your solution finally!! Yes, it worked. Ain't that a little tricky? Thanks.

Comment: looks like you did the hard work. Wanna edit that into an answer or provide as you own? Don't mind.

Comment: also, more efficient to use _refined_keywords = re.sub('-+','-' , ''.join(i.replace(" ","-") for i in elem.lower() if i not in spec_char))_  as less function calls.

Comment: I've kicked out the link. You should include the one in your answer that you have shown in pastebin so that it may be of any help for future readers. Thanks.